# Hashable == method does not detect difference between two objects swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, hashable, equatable

I implemented the class below:

```
    class Table : Hashable {

    var uid : Int
    var timeRemaining : Int?
    var currentPrice : Double?
    var hashValue: Int {
        return uid.hashValue
    }

    static func ==(lhs: Table, rhs: Table) -> Bool {
        return lhs.uid == rhs.uid && lhs.timeRemaining == rhs.timeRemaining && lhs.currentPrice == rhs.currentPrice
    }

    init (uid: Int, timeRemaining: Int?, currentPrice: Double?) {
        self.uid = uid
        self.timeRemaining = timeRemaining
        self.currentPrice = currentPrice
    }
}
```

I've also defined an array of objects of this class:

```
private var tables = [Table]()
```

Next, I have the following method which runs every second:

```
func updateAuctions() {
    let oldItems = tables
    let newItems = oldItems
    for table in newItems {
        let oldPrice = table.currentPrice!
        let timeRemaining = table.timeRemaining!
        table.currentPrice = oldPrice + 0.50
        table.timeRemaining = timeRemaining - 1
    }
    let changes = diff(old: oldItems, new: newItems)

    collectionView.reload(changes: changes, section: 0) { (complete) in
        if (complete) {
            self.tables = newItems
        }
    }
}
```

This uses the DeepDiff framework described here: https://github.com/onmyway133/DeepDiff

My goal is to refresh the `UICollectionView` with the changes made to the `tables` array, however no changes are detected by the framework, even though my `==` method checks that the `timeRemaining` and `currentPrice` match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> let newItems = oldItems

Since both array contain object instances, wouldn't they just point to the same objects? So when you iterate through `newItems` and changing values, you are essentially changing values of `oldItems` too. You can verify this by printing the values of both array after the `for` loop.

Maybe you can try something similar to the following?

```
func updateAuctions() {
    let oldItems = tables
    let newItems = [Table]()
    for item in oldItems {
        newItems.append(Table(uid: item.uid, timeRemaining: item.timeRemaining! - 1, currentPrice: item.currentPrice! + 0.50))
    }
    let changes = diff(old: oldItems, new: newItems)

    collectionView.reload(changes: changes, section: 0) { (complete) in
        if (complete) {
            self.tables = newItems
        }
    }
}
```